# On Nook Color, is there some kind of API to the reader functionality?

Tags: android, nook

In other words, if I want to make a custom user experience around the reader, is there a way to do it? I imagine for example that the reader could be a Content Provider for the books. Does anyone know if there's any way to do that?

Comment: You might try https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from their development team: "NO".